# Help with Accordion control in WPF, VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/538/

I added the WPFtookit and System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit to my references of my project.

In my xaml, at the top I added:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
```

as part of my ResourceDictionary element.

When I then try to do:

```
<toolkit:
```

Accordion and AccordionItem do not show.  The first thing I see is "ButtonBaseBehavior."  Am I missing something?  (I'm pretty new to VS, WPF and the like).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using 2010 with .Net 4.0 the namespaces are colliding.  There is no Accordian in the net framework (4.0) and the old toolkit can't be used side by side.  You will have to create your own.